# Usage of "Jump in" to mean start an activity

Tags: usage

I was in the gym waiting for a machine and I asked the guy near it if he is using the machine. He replied: "Yes, but I am resting now. Do you wanna jump in?". (As a note, the machine had nothing to do with physical action of jumping)

I am not sure if **jump in** is applicable in this situation. As far as I know, it is usually used by a speaker to prepare the audience to change subject immediately. But, I am not sure about using it for starting a physical activity is common and sounds natural to a native speaker.

Comment: **jump in** is most often used as an invitation to someone to get into a vehicle. In this case, from the context it sounds as though the person who had been using the machine was offering you a chance to use it while he rested.

Comment: Yes, I understood what he meant. But, is it idiomatic to use "jump in" in this context?

Comment: You don't say where you are, but in British English we call it 'jumping the queue' if one person takes the place of another while they are both waiting to do something.

Comment: Yes, **jump in** is used when people are talking and you ask the person who hasn't spoken if they want to jump in. Or you yourself jump into the ongoing discussion. The thing is that people use things loosely in speech, so I understand jump in re the gym thing but would not say it myself if thinking straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Jump in' isn't a phrase with a single idiomatic meaning - it is contextual. In this context, 'jump in' seems to means to *jump the queue/line* and go in front of someone else. When someone joins the middle of a queue instead of going to the end it is called 'queue jumping', although sometimes you may be invited to legitimately 'jump in' to the queue at a particular point.

In the context you perhaps thought of - beginning an activity - 'jump in' is a metaphor that references jumping into a swimming pool. It denotes a sudden start to an activity, become active quickly and perhaps skipping steps that might be for beginners.

And of course, it could mean other things in other contexts. There are lots of things that it may be idiomatic to speak of 'jumping' into.